# MYSQL: Union operator to add a 'total' row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, union

I have created the below SQL query to calculate the total income from leases within the next 12 months .

```
SELECT DISTINCT apartment.addressLine1, lease.monthlyRent, lease.duration,  lease.roomNumber, lease.monthlyRent*lease.duration AS totalLeaseRent
    FROM `lease`
    INNER JOIN apartment on (lease.roomNumber) = (apartment.roomNumber)
    left Join tenantLease on tenantLease.leaseID = lease.leaseID
    WHERE tenantLease.live = 1 AND lease.duration <= 12
```

This returns the following result:

```
AddressLine1    monthlyRent Duration(months)  roomNumber    totalLeaseRent
Chlorine Gardens1200        9                 GF02          10800
May Road        800         12                GF03          9600
Beech Hill      900         8                 BG06          7200
Ash Avenue      1000        12                AA04          12000
```

I now want to be able to have another row to include the total of the totalLeaseRent. Like this:

```
AddressLine1    monthlyRent Duration(months)  roomNumber    totalLeaseRent
    Chlorine Garden1200     9                 GF02          10800
    May Road        800         12            GF03          9600
    Beech Hill      900         8             BG06          7200
    Ash Avenue      1000        12            AA04          12000
    TOTAL                                                   *total*
```

I have tried the following code but keep getting the error code:
1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT apartment.addressLine1, lease.monthlyRent, lease.duration,  lease.roomNumber, lease.monthlyRent*lease.duration AS totalLeaseRent
FROM `lease`
INNER JOIN apartment on (lease.roomNumber) = (apartment.roomNumber)
left Join tenantLease on tenantLease.leaseID = lease.leaseID
WHERE tenantLease.live = 1 AND lease.duration <= 12

UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', SUM(lease.monthlyRent * lease.duration)
FROM lease
```

How do I get this query to run?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: We have to follow following three points while working with set operation

1- Each SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns

2- The columns must also have similar data types

3- The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

```
SELECT DISTINCT apartment.addressLine1, 
    lease.monthlyRent, 
    lease.duration,  
    lease.roomNumber, 
    lease.monthlyRent*lease.duration AS totalLeaseRent
FROM `lease`
INNER JOIN apartment on (lease.roomNumber) = (apartment.roomNumber)
left Join tenantLease on tenantLease.leaseID = lease.leaseID
WHERE tenantLease.live = 1 AND lease.duration <= 12
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', NULL, NULL, NULL, SUM(lease.monthlyRent * lease.duration)
FROM lease
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much, I have spent so much time trying to solve this!