# Get sum of column below the column in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, subquery

I have the following query:

```
select 
   product_name, 
   (select bid_price 
    from bids 
    where bid_id = current_bid_id) as final_price 
from items 
where close_date > '2023/01/01' 
  and close_date < '2023/02/01';
```

which outputs:

```
product_name final_price
  ball          20
  bat           30
hockey_stick    50
```

Instead of this, I want either:

```
product_name final_price
  ball          20
  bat           30
hockey_stick    50
  total         100
```

or

```
product_name final_price total
  ball          20        100
  bat           30        100
hockey_stick    50        100
```

I'm struggling on how to do this as its an alias column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL: Union operator to add a 'total' row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47530614/mysql-union-operator-to-add-a-total-row)

Comment: ```
select product_name, (select bid_price from bids where bid_id = current_bid_id) as final_price from items where close_date > '2023/01/01' and close_date< '2023/02/01'
UNION ALL
select 'Total', sum(final_price) as sp from (select (select bid_price from bids where bid_id = current_bid_id) as final_price from items where close_date> '2023/01/01' and close_date < '2023/02/01') as sp;

```

But I have to copy that whole bit again, which I rather not, any way to use just the alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: presumably the price selection subquery in the `select` clause always returns at most one row (otherwise you query would error), so it could be expressed as a left join (or even as an inner join, if there always is a bid to match the item).

Then: we can add easily add another column to the resultset that computes the total of all prices using window functions:

```
select i.product_name, 
    b.bid_price as final_price,
    sum(b.bid_price) over() as total_price
from items i
left join bids b on b.bid_id = i.current_bid_id
where i.close_date >= '2023-01-01' and i. close_date < '2023-02-01';
```

I slightly changed the date filtering, assuming that `close_date` is of a date-like datatype and that you want to filter on the entire day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
i.product_name, 
(SELECT bid_price FROM bids WHERE bid_id = i.current_bid_id) AS final_price,
COUNT(*) AS total_bids,
SUM((SELECT bid_price FROM bids WHERE bid_id = i.current_bid_id)) AS total_price FROM items AS i  INNER JOIN bids AS b ON i.current_bid_id = b.bid_id WHERE i.close_date > '2023-01-01' AND i.close_date < '2023-02-01' GROUP BY i.product_name;
```

Comment: I don't think this works, it only returns a single row

Answer (score 0):

You can use: [GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html#:%7E:text=clause%20permits%20a-,WITH%20ROLLUP,-modifier%20that%20causes)

```sql
select 
    case when product_name is null then 'TOTAL' else product_name END as product_name,  
    sum(final_price)
from items 
group by product_name with rollup
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/rNWmd4NO)

results:

| product_name | sum(final_price) |
| --- | --- |
| ball | 20 |
| bat | 30 |
| hockey_stick | 50 |
| TOTAL | 100 |

Comment: A new statement was found, but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near "with" at position 156)

I get this syntax error

Comment: I am using mariaDB on this version: 10.4.27-MariaDB

Comment: This statement also works on MariaDB 10.4 (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/pVmkHOBZ)  So there must be some typing error on your side.... 

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Zf-Sas6i

have a look at this. This is my Db format. Its because its pulling from another table.

Comment: Take a look at: https://dbfiddle.uk/2rgK8ALx